# Can we create and save dataframe in DSE Spark without enabling hive?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datastax-enterprise

I am using DataStax version 5.1.7. I have disabled Hadoop in DSE.

And when I convert an existing  rdd into dataframe, then I am getting following error -

```
"com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.NoSuchFileException : File not found : /tmp/hive"
```

Am I missing something or I need to change something?

Thanks In Advance?

Comment: What do you mean you disabled Hadoop in DSE? How you did it?

Comment: Sorry I did not disable hadoop, I just disabled Solr and as I am using 5.1.7 version so in 5.1.7 version hive functionality has been removed.
Now I am using only Cassandra and Spark of DataStax.